# get data from data table under some condition

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq

Q:

I have a DataTable , i want to get data according to some condition.(`Where()`)

```
MyTable.Select().Where()
```

How to do this if the condition (type = 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = MyTable.AsEnumerable()
                                   .Where(row => row.Field<int>("type") == 0);
```

Comment: then if i wanna to get a specific field value in that row how to get it?

Comment: You can take one of the rows (eg, `rows.First()`) and write `row.Field<SomeType>("FieldName")`

Comment: `IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = TableList.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("StudentCode") == int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text));`

Comment: but i get
Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: That means that your field isn't an `int`.

Comment: @SLaks how to use 'and' condition in where?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
var query = from r in dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
where r.Field<int>("Type") == 0
select new
{
     r.Field<string>(“Column1”), 
     r.Field<string>(“Column2”),
     r.Field<string>("ColunmEtc")
}
```